# Pip3 installs in .local directory despite correct python version

Tags: ubuntu, pip, path

Recently my pip3 decided to install all my packages in the wrong directory, even though it should install into the right python directory. It should install packages in '/usr/bin/python3/' but instead it goes to '/home/pepijn/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages'. 'which python3' points to a different version than 'python3 -m pip -V'

```
pepijn@pepijn-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S340-14IWL:~$ which python3.10
/usr/bin/python3

python3 -m pip -V
pip 23.3.1 from /home/pepijn/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)

pip3 -V
pip 23.3.1 from /home/pepijn/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
```

Every time I install a package, i get also 'Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable'

```
python3 -m pip install word2number
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: word2number in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (1.1)
```

What is happening? And would it be a bad idea to change the $PATH variable to '/usr/bin/python3/'?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Defaulting+to+user+installation+because+normal+site-packages+is+not+writeable

Comment: Your `/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages` is writeable only for root, not for users. You can do `sudo pip install` but that's very much not recommended. The only package that should be installed that way is `virtualenv`. Everything else should go into Python virtual environments. Or user directories, like in your case.